# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier node.js

Tags: nodejs

Estoy empezando con esto del web scraping en node.js y estaba viendo un tutorial en youtube donde hacian este codigo pero al querer ejecutarlo en la consola me sale este error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

**Este es mi código**

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeter')

async function scrapeProduct(url){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="landingImage"]')
    const src = await el.getProperty('src')
    const srcTxt = await src.jsonValue()

    console.log({srcTxt})
}


scrapeProduct('https://www.amazon.com.mx/dp/B08DKYLK4D/?coliid=I25VA9XEG65PV3&colid=3MEORLHJ0QSTX&psc=1')
```

Comment: Porque hay una variable `[el]`?

Comment: para poder desestructurarlo por que estoy sacando el xpath que esta entre paréntesis, y su primer elemento entrara en esa variable ósea `[el]` por que el xpath devuelve un array entonces lo meto en esa variable para usarlo después en el código , pero ya lo he podido arreglar, nunca supe por que era pero solo me funciono de la nada

Answer (score 0):

detecté 2 errores pero no el tuyo.

Prueba con esto y si sigues con problema vuelve a preguntar y haz referencia a la pregunta en un comentario a ésta.

Los problemas eran:

1. el nombre del módulo estaba errado en el require
2. faltaba un await en newPage

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function scrapeProduct(url){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="landingImage"]')
    const src = await el.getProperty('src')
    const srcTxt = await src.jsonValue()

    console.log({srcTxt})
}


scrapeProduct('https://www.amazon.com.mx/dp/B08DKYLK4D/?coliid=I25VA9XEG65PV3&colid=3MEORLHJ0QSTX&psc=1')
```

Te hago dos recomendaciones:

1. En stack overflow conviene que digas qué versiones de node.js y de puppeteer (o de los módulos sobre los que estés preguntando) estás usando.
2. Usa Visual Studio Code que va marcándote los errores mientras escribes.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo pude resolver :)